# Loop to arrange matching values in columns, leave cell blank in absence of match

Tags: excel, vba, macros

```
100         300
200         500
300         700
800         400
500         200 
600         100
```

I would like to take two columns of numbers (column A and column C) and arrange them so that matches are placed within the same row, while staying in their respective columns. Both columns will end up in ascending order. If there is no matching value in the other column, I would like there to be a space placed there. Here is what the columns would look like after running the macro:

```
100         100
200         200  
300         300
            400
500         500
600
            700
800
```

I know I need to set up a loop to have it run through the columns and if a match is found in the other column, move the matching value up or down its column to the row of its respective match. It would be something like this, starting out with the active cell as "A1", the first cell in column A:

```
If Not ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0,2) Then
```

And then have it find the matching value in column C, then cut and paste it into the same row as the active cell, or leave an empty space in column C in the row of the active cell if there is no matching value in column C.

My question is, how do I set up the If-Then statements in the loop to make this macro run the way I need it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("numbers") '<--| change "numbers" to your actual worksheet name
        With Intersect(.Range("A1").Resize(, 2).EntireColumn, .UsedRange)
            .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value = .Columns(1).Value
            .Offset(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value = .Columns(2).Value
            With .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(2 * .Rows.Count, 1)
                .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
                .Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
                Order .Offset(, -2).Resize(.Rows.Count / 2), .Parent.Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
                Order .Offset(, -1).Resize(.Rows.Count / 2), .Parent.Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
                .ClearContents
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub Order(rngToOrder As Range, sortingRng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    ReDim arr(1 To sortingRng.Rows.Count)

    For Each cell In rngToOrder
        arr(sortingRng.Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row) = cell.Value
    Next cell
    rngToOrder.Resize(sortingRng.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

Comment: For the second Sub procedure, are rngToOrder and sortingRng being declared? Wouldnt "Dim" go before the both of them?

Comment: They are declared in the Sub arguments list. Did it work for you?

Comment: I get an Object variable or With block variable not set error, and it highlights this row: arr(sortingRng.Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row) = cell.Value

Comment: It's not finding the "cell.Value" in "sortingRng". I wrote the code for data in columns A and B only i.e. No other data in "numbers" worksheet. Are your data like that?

Comment: Ok, now I got it to work. I had my data in columns A and C, so I just moved column C over to column B and it did just the trick. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't look very straight forward, so gave it a try. Try this code. data is in col A and B

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("A1:A6").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A6")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Range("B1:B6").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B1:B6")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    lr1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr = WorksheetFunction.Min(lr1, lr2)
    i = 1

    Do While (i <= lr)
        a = Range("A" & i)
        b = Range("B" & i)

        If Not (a = b) Then
            If (Range("A" & i) > Range("B" & i)) Then
                Range("A" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Else
                Range("B" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End If

        End If
        i = i + 1
        lr1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lr2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lr = WorksheetFunction.Min(lr1, lr2)
    Loop
End Sub
```